# GCP: what's the limit on concurrent sessions on a single service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internet-of-things

We're planning to run a project in which a large amount of sensors will collect data and send them into GCP / Google Compute Pub/Sub queue for processing.

I've created a service account to be deployed onto those sensors - the question is, how many sensors can use that same service account simultaneously?

This thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059957/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-service-accounts-that-a-project-can-have-in-the-goo
suggests there's a limit of 600 tokens per service account, but I'm not sure whether that's the same nor was I able to confirm that number.

Suggestions would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thread you've linked in your question is out-of-date as I was unable to find anything in terms of limits of that kind. That setup should work without any issues, but be sure that your expected throughput to Pub/Sub doesn't hit any of the quotas associated with your project, that's really the only restriction I could find.